# Getting an error in tkinter and message encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tkinter

I Was working a tcp chat room and  when i run it it shows nicknames and who joined but the message doesnt go through and after trying to send a message the 4th time it show the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "besthost.py", line 59, in write
    self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

The host file is

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from tkinter import simpledialog

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9091


class Client:

    def __init__(self, host, port):

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

        msg = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()

        self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("nickname", "please choose a nickname", parent=msg)
        self.gui_done = False

        self.running = True
        gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
        gui_thread.start()
        receive_thread.start()

    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.configure(bg="darkolivegreen")

        self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="chat", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="message", bg="lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height =3)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20,pady=5)

        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text="send", command=self.write)
        self.send_button.config(font=("arial", 12))
        self.send_button.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.gui_done = True
        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)
        self.win.mainloop()

    def write(self):
        message = f"{self.nickname}:{self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"
        self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.sock.close()
        exit(0)

    def receive(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message=='NICK':
                    self.sock.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.insert('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                break
            except:
                print("error")
                self.sock.close()
                break


client = Client(HOST, PORT)
```

The server file is

```
import socket
import threading

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9091

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print(f"{nicknames[client.index(client)]})")
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break


def receive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"connected with {str(address)}!")

        client.send("NICK".encode('utf-8'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024)

        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        print(f"nicknames of client is {nickname}")
        broadcast(f"{nickname} connected successfully!\n".encode('utf-8'))
        client.send("connected to the server".encode('utf-8'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()


print("server running")
receive()
```

I tried searching but i didnt see anyone with this issue and i dont think there are any programming errors

If anyone has an idea whats wrong please let me know .
Thanks

Comment: First of all, in your client you never destroy the `msg` window. Second of all, you shouldn't be accessing `tkinter` widgets/functions from threads other than the one where you created the `tk.Tk()` window. Third of all, this problem looks like a `socket` problem from the error. If I am correct, please remove the `tkinter` tag from the question.

Comment: I am also  getting an error in tkinter in __init__ as shown in the error box

Comment: You used `command=self.write`, so in the traceback that will appear as `return self.func(*args)` from `tkinter/__init__.py`. The actual error comes from the `socket.write(...)`.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which line of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. maybe code looks correct but you may run functions in wrong order and both sides may wait for message at the same time and then it make problem.

Comment: you don't have to use `str()` inside `f-string`

Comment: did you run server before client?

Comment: Yes i have used server before client

Comment: your the biggest mistake is `except:` without printing information about problem. you get error `'socket' object has no attribute 'index'` . Check `except Exception as ex: print (ex)`

Comment: after correcting previous error I prints me another problem: `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your the biggest mistake is `except:` without printing information about problem.

I use

```
except Exception as ex: 
    print (ex)
    # ... rest ...
```

and first it shows me

```
 'socket' object has no attribute 'index'
```

because you forgot `s` in word `clients` in line

```
print(f"{nicknames[clients.index(client)]})")
```

Next it shows me

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

because you send `str` instead of `bytes` in next line - and you need `encode()`

```
broadcast(message.encode('utf-8'))
```

After these changes it start working for me.

---

```
def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')  # convert bytes to string
            print(f"{nicknames[clients.index(client)]})")  # forgot `s`
            broadcast(message.encode('utf-8'))  # convert string back to bytes
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:', ex)

            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break
```